# How does Symfony2 find the correct controller without extending the ControllerResolver?

Tags: php, symfony

I've been looking at Symfony2 code and I can't figure out how it figures out the correct controller to use without extending/overriding the functions of the ControllerResolver class. I don't think the default ControllerResolver is able to find the controller for something like BundleName:Bundle:action to a controller.

Comment: Did you have a look at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser ?

Comment: And what is defined in routing is BundleName:Controller:action

Comment: Oh yes, ControllerNameParser was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Controller is resolved in the HTTPKernel Class (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php) . This is what happens there

```
    // load controller
    if (false === $controller = $this->resolver->getController($request)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Unable to find the controller for path "%s". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?', $request->getPathInfo()));
    }
```

Once the controller is resolved , the controller class will be there in the __controller property of the request